# JavaScript code does not execute in a window opened by a script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to open a new window, with some code in it and a button that should alert when you click on it.
My code is something like this:

```js
$('#PREVIEW').click(function() {
    n = window.open("preview.html", "_blank");
    var result = DSLExGenerator.parse($('#original').val());
    var res = result.replace(/>,</g, "><");
    n.document.write(res + '<br/><button id=\"results\">Resultados</button><script type=\"text/JavaScript\" src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js\"></script><script type=\"text/JavaScript\">$(document).ready(function() {  $(\"#results\").click(function() {   var aux = 0;   var nPreg = 0;   $(\'input[value=\"1\"]\').each(function() {       nPreg++;   });   $(\'input:checked\').each(function() {       if($(this).attr(\"ver\") == \"V\"){        aux++;       }   });   alert(\"Ha acertado \" + aux.toString() + \" de \" + nPreg + \" preguntas.\");  });});</script>');
  });
```

```html
<html><head></head><body><h1>Titulo: Titulo  Fecha: 01,01,2015  Profesor: Profesor  Asignatura: Asignatura</h1><p class="question">1. Pregunta 1</p><ul class="answers"><input type="radio" name="q0" value="1" id="q01" ver="F"><label for="q01">Respuesta 1 1</label><br><input type="radio" name="q0" value="2" id="q02" ver="V"><label for="q02">Respuesta 1 2</label><br></ul><p class="question">2. Pregunta 2</p><ul class="answers"><input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" id="q11" ver="V"><label for="q11">Respuesta 1 2</label><br><input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" id="q12" ver="V"><label for="q12">Respuesta 2 2</label><br></ul><p class="question">3. Pregunta 3</p><ul class="answers"><input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" id="q21" ver="V"><label for="q21">Respuesta 1 3</label><br><input type="radio" name="q2" value="2" id="q22" ver="V"><label for="q22">Respuesta 3 2</label><br><input type="radio" name="q2" value="3" id="q23" ver="F"><label for="q23">Respuesta 3 3</label><br></ul><p class="question">4. Pregunta 4</p><ul class="answers"><input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" id="q31" ver="V"><label for="q31">Respuesta 1 4</label><br><input type="radio" name="q3" value="2" id="q32" ver="V"><label for="q32">Respuesta 4 2</label><br></ul><br><button id="results">Resultados</button><script type="text/JavaScript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script><script type="text/JavaScript">$(document).ready(function() {  $("#results").click(function() {   var aux = 0;   var nPreg = 0;   $('input[value="1"]').each(function() {       nPreg++;   });   $('input:checked').each(function() {       if($(this).attr("ver") == "V"){        aux++;       }   });   alert("Ha acertado " + aux.toString() + " de " + nPreg + " preguntas.");  });});</script></body></html>
```

The problem is if I manually copy the HTML code and save it into a file it works, but it doesn't work on the generated window.

Comment: Is string provided to `document.write` valid ? Is `jQuery` defined at new `window` ?

Comment: Yes, the problem is the new window button doesn't work, but if i copy the html code of the generated window (with chrome's element inspector) and save it into an html file it works properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `\` before `/` at closing `script` tags. Also, `document` is already loaded , `$(document).ready(fn)` does not fire. Try substituting 
an IIFE for `$(document).ready(fn)`

```
(function() {
  $("#results").click(/* do stuff */)
}());
```

---

```
    n = window.open("", "_blank");
   // var result = DSLExGenerator.parse($('#original').val());
   // var res = result.replace(/>,</g, "><");
    n.document.write('<br/><button id=\"results\">Resultados</button><script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js\"><\/script><script type=\"text/javascript\">(function() {        $(\"#results\").click(function() {alert(\"preview\");});}());<\/script>');
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/ac7ax95L/

Comment: Nice! Thank you very much, the solution was using an IIFE instead of $(document).ready(fn).